# Google Cloud Airflow Composer Produce Disk Cost "WHY" or "FROM WHERE"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

We have a problem. When we created airflow composer on google cloud platform. Disk price is come up in the billing report. But we didn't know "why do we have a cost or from which tool produce this cost?"

If you have any idea about this problem, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is coming from Databae storage.

Here you can find all details of the pricing - broken down by SKUs, I guess you should be able to find detailed answer there.

https://cloud.google.com/composer/pricing